# In postgresql, how to translate a string using a lookup table values as matching_string and replace_string with variable lengths

Tags: sql, postgresql, translate

I have a lookup table for translation purpose

| matching_string | replace_string |
| --- | --- |
| A | °A |
| B | B |
| C | Ç |
| °D | D |

I want to apply this translation in way
ABCD will change to  °ABÇD  and ABC°D to °ABÇD

Note : the character length are different in the lookup table. there is no limit on the entries in lookup table.

The ultimate aim is to use this solution to apply on large data - something like :

```
select translate(first_name, 'ABC°D', '°ABÇD') , translate(last_name, 'ABC°D', '°ABÇD') 
from names_table;
```

How can I build solution that fits my scenario ?

I have tried using `translate` and found it will only work if the matching and replace strings are of same length. `regex_replace` is letting me do only one replace one time and i had to nest n number to achieve this.

here is the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2o1W3Pa7xHjMWoc6krQw3m/0)

Comment: I think a database is not the best option to do language processing and this should probably be done in a programming language. The best SQL solution (albeit not very efficient) could be to use a recursive CTE to process the translations one by one, for each entry. Doable, but not very performant.

Comment: thank you @TheImpaler for your response. sadly I was moving some of the bulk data operations from java to sql, it seems I need to let this remain in the java code itself.